# In Excel, how can my drop down selection change which columns are hidden or unhidden?

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code is below. I have a dropdown box with 9 selectable options.  Each option hides or unhides specific columns.  My current code works well to hide what isn't needed. However, when I select a different drop down option, it will not reset to show only what I need to see.  Essentially only building off the previous selection.

```
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = ("$F$1") Then
        
        'LID
        If Target.Text = "LID" Then
            Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("I:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Text = "RESET" Then
        Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
        
        'Whole - HARD FIXED
        If Target.Text = "Whole -Hard Fixed" Then
            Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("K:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Text = "RESET" Then
        Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
        
        'Whole - FIXED W TRIGGER
        If Target.Text = "Whole -Fixed w Trigger" Then
            Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("L:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Text = "RESET" Then
        Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
        
        'Whole - HIGH/LOW
        If Target.Text = "Whole -High/Low" Then
            Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Text = "RESET" Then
        Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
        
         'VALUE ADDED
        If Target.Text = "Value Added" Then
            Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("L:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Text = "RESET" Then
        Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
       
        'FIXED LANDED
        If Target.Text = "Fixed Landed" Then
            Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("J:P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Text = "RESET" Then
        Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
        
        'FIXED QUARTERLY
        If Target.Text = "Fixed Quarterly" Then
            Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("L:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Text = "RESET" Then
        Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
        
        'HIGH/LOW QUARTERLY
        If Target.Text = "H/L Quarterly" Then
            Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("I:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Text = "RESET" Then
        Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
        
          'FIXED MONTHLY
        If Target.Text = "Fixed Monthly" Then
            Columns("G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("I:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("L:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        ElseIf Target.Text = "RESET" Then
        Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
       
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Unhide all columns first before hiding? Basically you need to call `Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False` it seems.

Comment: Exactly what @BigBen suggested.  If you place it immediately after `If Target.Address = ("$F$1") Then` then any change to F1 will show the columns before hiding any relevant columns.

Comment: YES!  Thank you both!  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Folding in the excellent "unhide all columns first" advice:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As String
    
    If Target.Address = ("$F$1") Then
        Me.Columns("A:V").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Select Case Target.Text
            Case "LID": rng = "G1,I1:O1,Q1"
            Case "Whole -Hard Fixed": rng = "G1,I1,K1:N1,Q1"
            Case "Whole -Fixed w Trigger": rng = "G1,I1,J1,L1:N1,Q1"
            Case "Whole -High/Low": rng = "G1,I1,J1,K1,Q1"
            'etc etc
            Case Else: rng = ""
        End Select
        If Len(rng) > 0 Then Me.Range(rng).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If 'F1
    
End Sub
```